# Centre align text that has extra letter spacing applied

Tags: css, alignment

What's the best way to centre align some text that has an increased `letter-spacing` so that it's actually in the centre of its container? The text is in an `h5` tag that is centre aligned within the parent `div` but sits noticeably to the left because `letter-spacing` applies to the right of each letter. I could manually add some left padding but that wouldn't stay consistently aligned if the browser zoom level was changed.

**Is there a way to calculate the spacing between each letter, either using css or JavaScript? Is there a better way to insert spacing between letters so everything is centrally aligned?**

The container div already has `20px` padding on all sides so I really need to add `0.75em` to the left padding. Here's the relevant css for the `h5` and container tags:

```
.container {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.container h5 {
    font-size: 33px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The container looks like this:

[image: container]

Comment: Could try adding &nbsp; at the start of the text. May balance it out.

Comment: Sticks it `11px` too far the other way unfortunately - good shout though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just specify `padding-left: 1.5em;` for your `.container h5`?

Comment: It's been a long day - top shout Matthew

Comment: Turns out it's just Chrome on my dekstop - the scale rate of my Chrome 24 for Windows is bugged such that letter spacing and padding do not scale at the same rate. http://jsfiddle.net/MVHm8/

Comment: Hmm, you are indeed correct - wonder how I'm going to get around that one? +1 for pointing that out. Changing the padding to `2em` on the container has made no difference (thinking out loud here!) as it's due to the rate of scale

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution could be to specify `margin-right: -1.5em;` for `.container h5`, so you won't add extra space into your container when aligned.

Answer (score -1):

It's old, but another solution (trick) is to add a space between the characters. For me it's the best solution, because i want a big space between the characters ;)

Comment: That's a great mention, but no solution is provided. Provide a solution.